# How can I use re.sub to actually replace the filenames?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I put together a regular expression that works using the mac program [Patterns](http://krillapps.com/patterns/), when I use the code in my python script, I cannot get the changes made to the filenames. I know that you need to assign the output of `re.sub` to a new string, which is a common error. I did that, but I still cannot get the correct results.

Here is my code with the given file names as input:

`real.time.With.bill.maher.JUST.OVERTIME.2014.01.31.WEB-DL.Shadoe`

`real time with bill maher 2014 01 24 hdtv x264-2hd.mp4`

`Real Time With Bill Maher 2014.02.07.hdtv.x264-2hd.mp4`

```
import re
import os

path = "/Users/USERNAME/Movies"
pattern = "(real[. ]time[. ]with[. ]bill[. ]maher[. ])"
replacement = "Real Time with Bill Maher "

def renamer(path, pattern, replacement):
    for dirpath,_,file in os.walk(path):
        for oldname in file:
            if re.search(pattern, oldname, re.I):
                newname = re.sub(pattern, replacement, oldname)
                newpath = os.path.join(dirpath, newname)
                oldpath = dirpath + "/" + oldname
                print newpath + " < new"
                print oldpath
                os.rename(oldpath, newpath)

renamer(path, pattern, replacement)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is missing `re.I` flag in `re.sub` call:

```
>>> pattern = "(real[. ]time[. ]with[. ]bill[. ]maher[. ])"
>>> replacement = "Real Time with Bill Maher "
>>> re.sub(pattern, replacement, 'real.time.With.bill.maher.JUST.OVERTIME.2014.01.31.WEB-DL.Shadoe')
'real.time.With.bill.maher.JUST.OVERTIME.2014.01.31.WEB-DL.Shadoe'
>>> re.sub(pattern, replacement, 'real.time.With.bill.maher.JUST.OVERTIME.2014.01.31.WEB-DL.Shadoe', flags=re.I)
'Real Time with Bill Maher JUST.OVERTIME.2014.01.31.WEB-DL.Shadoe'
```

You should specify `flags` as keyword argument, otherwise it is recognized as `count` (replace count) argument.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! FYI: The code works without explicitly defining the flags (`flags=`)

Comment: @macmadness86, `flags` is optional. BTW, What do you mean `works`? Does not raise exception?

Comment: Exactly. And writes the new file names properly. I can't mark your answer correct for another 30 seconds.